# AngularJS fire function on-click anchor links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm hoping someone can help me achieve a clean and effective way of firing a function when anchor links, with a specific css class, are clicked.

I could do this using `ng-click` but I feel that is a bit of a messy and unmaintainable solution: it would mean adding `ng-click` to each of the anchor links I want to track.

My navigation links currently look like this:

```
<li id="item1" class="foo"><a href="#/item1">CLICK ME</a></li>
```

I'd like to emulate the functionality of `ng-click` in a similar manner to the following JQuery stubb (which doesn't seem to work in my configuration):

```
$('.foo a').on('click', function(){
    //do some code 
});
```

**tl;dr**

I'd like an AngularJS way to execute a function when an element with a specific css class is clicked.

Please let me know if I haven't described this well enough.

Thanks in advance,

JohnD

Comment: Do you mean when the element itself or any `a` tags under it are clicked?

Comment: @runTarm When any `a` tags are clicked under it. You nailed it on the head anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write directive and apply it to root element.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dacmpyeq/)

```
<div ng-app="app" foo-dir>
    <li id="item1" class="foo"><a href="#/item1">CLICK ME 1</a>

    </li>
    <li id="item2" class="foo"><a href="#/item2">CLICK ME 2</a>

    </li>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive("fooDir", function () {
    return {
        link: function ($scope) {
            $(".foo a").on("click", function (event) {
                alert($(this).html());
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've got that implemented and it works quite nicely! I've accepted your answer as it is more complete than runTarm's though very similar.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom directive like this:

```
.directive('foo', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        console.log('clicked! do some code here.');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/53gge6KUoEoedt1PD0RB?p=preview

Comment: I noticed your Plunker uses `element.on('click', function (e)` but your sample above uses `element.on('click', 'a', function (e)`.  By adding the element selector `'a'` I receive the following error. `[jqLite:onargs] jqLite#on() does not support the 'selector' or 'eventData' parameters`.

Comment: jqLite doesn't support it. You have to include jquery or find other ways around. This question has the `jquery` tag, so it is assumed jquery is there in my example.